# Importing public Key to Google KMS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, rsa, public-key, google-cloud-kms

**Use Case:** client will create public/private keys and provide me the public key. I'm suppose to Encrypt(RSA) the message with public Key and send the message to Client. client will decrypt the message with private Key

**Key Generation:** Client was generated the public/private keys by using openssl. commands given below.

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out private.pem 2048
openssl rsa -in private.pem -outform PEM -pubout -out public.pem
```

**Challenge:** I'm suppose to save the public key somewhere. since we are already utilizing the Google KMS, is there a way I can maintain only the public key in Google KMS ?
I have gone through https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/importing-a-key#create_importjob but
below command is failing with ***gcloud.kms.keys.versions.import) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Wrapped key is too short.***

Import Command Used:

```
gcloud kms keys versions import \
   --import-job {job_name} \
   --location {location} \
   --keyring {keyring}  \
   --key {key_name} \
   --algorithm "rsa-decrypt-oaep-2048-sha256"\
   --rsa-aes-wrapped-key-file public.pem
```

also I'm not able to convert public key to PCKS#8 DER format by executing below command. getting /***crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:745:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY***

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -inform PEM -outform DER \
    -in /path/to/publicKey.pem \
    -out /path/to/publicKey_formtted.pem
```

Comment: If your goal is to store the public key in a managed storage location, consider Google Cloud Secret Manager instead. KMS is the wrong service to store public keys. Note: to convert an RSA public key in PEM format to DER: **openssl pkey -pubin -in publicKey.pem -outform der -out publicKey.der** However, it is usually better to keep public keys in PEM format unless the binary format is required. Another item, you do not need to protect public keys in most cases, they are called **public** for a reason. It is the private key that must be protected.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud KMS is designed around securing private or secret keys. In most cryptographic protocols, public keys are not confidential, so you can just store it as metadata for your system and do the encryption locally in your application.

Thanks for using GCP and Cloud KMS.